# Copying of data from varchar2 to number in a same table

Tags: oracle10g

I have two columns and i need to copy of data from column VISITSAUTHORIZED to NEWVISITS, When i use below command to copy data i am getting an error message "invalid number".Can anyone correct this ?

```
 VISITSAUTHORIZED  VARCHAR2(10)
 NEWVISITS         NUMBER(8)
 SQL> update patientinsurance set NEWVISITS=VISITSAUTHORIZED ;
 ERROR at line 1:
 ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: This means you have values in your `VISITSAUTHORIZED` table which are not valid numbers. Possibly entered with group or (incorrect) decimal separators, but could be anything. Can you add a sample of the values to see if this can be workaround just with a number format mask?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of data you have in your old column. If it is all consistently formatted then you might be able to do:

```
update patientinsurance
set newvisits = to_number(visitsauthorized, '<format model>')
```

But it sounds more likely that you have something less easy to deal with. (The joys of storing data as the wrong datatype, which I assume is what you're now correcting). If there are rogue characters then you could use `translate` to get rid of them, perhaps, but you'd have to wonder about the integrity of the data and the values you end up with.

You can do something like this to display all the values that can't be converted, which may give you an idea of the best way to proceed - if there are only a few you might be able to correct them manually before re-running your update:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  newvisits number;
  number_format_exception exception;
  pragma exception_init(number_format_exception, -6502);
begin
  for r in (select id, visitsauthorized from patientinsurance) loop
    begin
      newvisits := to_number(r.visitsauthorized);
    exception
      when number_format_exception then
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode || ' ID ' || r.id
          || ' value ' || r.visitsauthorized);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This is guessing you have a unique identifier field called `ID`, but change that as appropriate for your table, obviously.

Another approach is to convert the numbers that are valid and skip over the rest, which you can do with an error logging table:

```
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'PATIENTINSURANCE');

merge into patientinsurance target
using (select id, visitsauthorized from patientinsurance) source
on (target.id = source.id)
when matched then
  update set target.newvisits = source.visitsauthorized
log errors into err$_patientinsurance reject limit unlimited;
```

You can then query the error table to see what failed:

```
select id, visitsauthorized, ora_err_number$
from err$_patientinsurance;
```

Or see which records in your main table have `newvisits` still `null`. Analysing your data should probably be the first step though.

---

If you want to strip out all non-numeric characters and treat whatever is left as a number then you can change the merge to do:

```
...
update set target.newvisits = regexp_replace(source.visitsauthorized,
  '[^[:digit:]]', null)
```

But then you probably don't need the merge, you can just do:

```
update patientinsurance set newvisits = regexp_replace(visitsauthorized,
  '[^[:digit:]]', null);
```

This will strip out any group or decimal separators as well, which might not be an issue, particularly as you're inserting into a number(8) column. But you could preserve those if you wanted to, by changing the pattern to `'[^[:digit:].,]'`... though that could give you other problems still, potentially.

You can also do this with `translate` if the regex is too slow.

Comment: update patientinsurance set newvisits = to_number(visitsauthorized, 'VARCHAR2(10)')  If i am using like this i am getting an error like this                                      
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01481: invalid number format model

Comment: @Kiran no no, that isn't a [number format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211); look at the data first. A model would be something like `'999,999'`, if you have data like say `'1,234'`. Entirely depends what is in the table.

Comment: When i am using merge procedure i am able copy only digits but i need all information in the visitsauthorized contains like (te44,700,ket99,500) to newvisits(te44,700,ket99,500) but i am copying only 700,500 values remaining values are getting err log so what i need to do next

Comment: @Kiran - you can't put characters into a number column. What are you expecting to be in `new visit` for those - `44` and `99`, or something else?

Comment: actually i am taking backup from visitsauthorized to new visits then how to get all the values if we loss the values of mixing characters and digits .

Comment: @Kiran - sorry, I don't understand. The columns are of different types; unless you make `newvisits` to be `varchar2(10)` as well then you will lose either the whole value or at best the characters for any values that contain non-digits. What do you want `new visits` to contain for those four values?

Comment: @Kiran - updated to show how to strip out non-numeric characters before conversion.

Comment: i got a solution @Alex Thanks for your valuable ideas