# Converting CLOB to NUMBER to compare - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, sqldatatypes, clob

I'm newbie to oracle and my question is easy, is possible to convert a CLOB field into NUMBER type to do a comparison.

I´ve tried using CAST and also with TO_NUMBER function but i did not get nothing working.

My attempts:

```
WHERE TO_NUMBER(clob_field) = 100 -> Error ORA-01722: NOT a valid number

WHERE CAST(clob_field as NUMBER) = 100 -> Error ORA-00932:Inconsistent datatypes
```

If this is not possible, which would be the best approach to do this?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Your `clob_field` has a non numeric.. atleast in one of the rows!

Comment: If you need to compare a CLOB with a number then you should review your database model because something is not right.

Comment: Is a database from an open source software project and it´s necessary to do this, in order to do a data migration from another database... I'd wish start this from zero but specs were given...

Comment: @OracleUser then i should try cast to varchar and then to number?¿ or something like that...

Comment: @Tommy - you need to look at the values in the column and see if they look like numbers, and if they generally do, then which are not convertible. Still seems weird to be using a `clob` to be holding a text value short enough to represent a number. (You could maybe adapt the PL/SQL block in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22102937/266304) to show you which values are not numbers).

Comment: @AlexPoole thx, i'll check your link. I see in that field of the table that sometimes it saves just a number and in many other records saves a large text...

Comment: `select regexp_substr(text,'[^[:digit:].]') from yourtable where regexp_like(text,'[^[:digit:].]');` Also should help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare it as varchar to get rid of the error message:

```
WHERE TRIM(clob_field) = '100'
```

If there is never any whitespace around the `100` you can skip the `TRIM`:

```
WHERE clob_field = '100'
```

Comment: @OracleUser It will not recognize for example `100.0` or `1E2` as `100` if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yup.. also "+1.0" <> "1"

Answer (score 2):

Cast it first to a `VARCHAR2` and then to a `NUMBER`:

```
CAST(CAST(clob_field AS VARCHAR2(200)) AS NUMBER(10))
```

Comment: This won't stop errors when `clob_field` cannot be converted into a number.

Comment: True, but sometimes you _know_ that they are numbers, when retrieving the values by parsing the `CLOB` with a regex.

Comment: Useful for grouping (used on a small INT a CLOB, knowing it was number stored) as:
... group BY CAST(CAST(value AS VARCHAR2(200)) AS NUMBER(1))